# Kendo window open() issue in IE 9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9, kendo-ui

On the click of a button, I am opening a kendoWindow which loads partial view.

This partial view also contains a kendo grid inside.

My issue with this is everything works fine in chrome, but there is an issue in IE.

Here is sample code -

```
if (!$popupContainer.data("kendoWindow")) {
                popUpWindow = $(windowId).kendoWindow({
                    actions: ["Close"],
                    draggable: true,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    title: title,
                    width: "900px",
                    close: onClose,
                    open: onOpen,
                    deactivate: function () { this.destroy(); }
                });
                popUpWindow.data("kendoWindow").center();
                popUpWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
}  
win.content('Loading....');
win.refresh
({
    url: "some action url which loads a partial view";
});
```

My issue with IE is it's working fine first and second time but the third time the popup is not opening immediately, it's taking some time and I don't want that.

I want that window to open saying loading and then load the grid.

I tried debugging it and found the that this line: `popUpWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();`

is not opening the window, it's opening only after the partial view is loaded.

Where as in chrome `open()` function opens the window immediately thus showing the loading text before the partial view is loaded.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have been trying to resolve this for two days and it's very infuriating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for someone who is facing into similar issues, I have found the reason for why I am getting this issue. This occurred because I was trying to open the window and refresh content in recursive ajax calls and the UI changes are not being updated in IE until all the requests are completed.

Comment: And that's why you should avoid AJAX calls within a partial view.  Use a model/viewmodel and a controller method to retrieve your data, if at all possible.